# php.ini error_log does not work anymore

Tags: php, error-log

yesterday I changed the php.ini file on my server setting up the error_log path. Then I made a test running a page with code errors, a file (php_errors.log) was created at the path specified. All perfect.

After this I started some tests and the php_errors.log file become a bit long, maybe 50 lines...not so much, then i tried to delete some lines but nothing, so I deleted manually php_errors.log

Today error_log does not work, if I run pages with errors they are only displayed on screen but there are no effects in php_errors.log, this file it is not even created by the server.

I did not make other changes...today i tried to remove, recreate the file and change the path in php.ini but nothing happens, i don't understand! do you?

Comment: what OS your server is using?

Comment: Can you try to run `phpinfo();` to see what it says about error logging? Did you restart your webserver?

Comment: look at phpinfo() output to see the location of the correct php.ini file to edit